# Why won't my basic PHP validation process in IE, FireFox or Opera?

Tags: php, internet-explorer, validation, firefox

The PHP based validation of my form does not work in the latest versions IE, Firefox or Opera. I click the submit button with empty values in my form fields to trigger validation but the page simply refreshes.

The odd thing is that validation and error messages work in Chrome and Safari.

View this for yourself here: http://www.directsponsor.org/contact/

**Can anyone advise me on known issues regarding why <strike>PHP might fail on certain browsers</strike> certain browsers behave differently?**

Apologies for the mountains of code in advance, though I presume its required:

## Here's the form:

```
    <form method="post" action="http://www.directsponsor.org/contact/">
  <fieldset>
  <ul>
  <?php if(isset($_POST['contactsubmit'])){
  if (!$contactnamevalidation){
  echo "<li class='contactfail'><p><img src='"; echo bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); echo "/images/icons/101-large.png'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;You did not input your <strong>name</strong>.</p></li>";
  }
  }
  ?>
  <li>
    <label for="contactname">Your name <em>(required)</em></label> 
    <input type="text" name="contactname" class="textbox" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['contactname'])) {echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['contactname'], ENT_QUOTES);    }?>">
 </li>
 <?php if(isset($_POST['contactsubmit'])){
  if (!$contactemailvalidation1){
  echo "<li class='contactfail'><p><img src='"; echo bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); echo "/images/icons/101-large.png'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;You did not input your <strong>email</strong>.</p></li>";
  }
  }
  ?>
 <?php if(isset($_POST['contactsubmit'])){
  if (!$contactemailvalidation2){
  echo "<li class='contactfail'><p><img src='"; echo bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); echo "/images/icons/101-large.png'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;You did not input a <strong>valid email</strong>.</p></li>";
  }
  }
  ?>
  <li>
    <label for="contactemail">Your email <em>(required)</em></label>
    <input type="text" name="contactemail" class="textbox" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['contactemail'])) {echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['contactemail'], ENT_QUOTES);    }?>">
 </li>
 <?php if(isset($_POST['contactsubmit'])){
  if (!$contactmessagevalidation){
  echo "<li class='contactfail'><p><img src='"; echo bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); echo "/images/icons/101-large.png'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;You did not input a <strong>message</strong>.</p></li>";
  }
  }
  ?>
  <li>
    <label for="contactmessage">Message <em>(required)</em></label>
    <textarea name="contactmessage"><?php if (isset($_POST['contactmessage'])) {echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['contactmessage'], ENT_QUOTES);    }?></textarea>
  </li>
  <li class="buttons">
  <label for="contactsubmit">&nbsp;</label><input type="image" src="/wp-content/themes/directsponsor/images/button-sendmessage.png" name="contactsubmit" value="Submit Message">

  <?php if(isset($_POST['contactsubmit'])){echo"<a href='http://www.directsponsor.org/contact/'><img src='/wp-content/themes/directsponsor/images/button-clearform.png'/></a>";} ?>
  </li>
  </ul>
  </fieldset>
  </form>
```

## Here's the (relevant part of the) validation:

```
    <?php 
if(isset($_POST['contactsubmit'])){
```

//Validation here.

```
}
?>
```

## The answer

As suggested by Dr. Molle, IE, FireFox and Opera handle the value of *images used as submit button* differently in comparison to Chrome and Safari.

My validation began with:

`if(isset($_POST['contactsubmit'])){`

IE, Firefox and Opera posts the following values:

```
//Values for image as a submit button.
contactsubmit_x
contactsubmit_y
```

Since both of these value are different to `contactsubmit`, the `if(isset())` condition isn't triggered. To rememdy this I needed to use a form element other than the *image as a submit button* such as the email field:

`if(isset($_POST['contactemail'])){`

This will trigger the condition for validation whether or not `contactemail` is empty or not.

Comment: PHP doesn't fail on browsers since it's processed server-side.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Would it be more correct to say that _certain browsers fail_ (rather than _PHP fails_) as per Dr.Molle's answer pertaining to the inconsistent browser handling of the value of images used as submit buttons? **Note: I edited the question - refer to the strike through text**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this:

```
if(isset($_POST['contactsubmit']))
```

this variable does'nt exists in the failing browsers, if you use an image-submit there are variables `$_POST['contactsubmit_x']` and `$_POST['contactsubmit_y']` instead.

It works in Chrome/Safari because they also send the variable "contactsubmit" if you set a value-attribute for the image-submit(but the occurence of this variable isn't reliable as you see).

But I would suggest  not to use those variables at all. It depends on the browser if those variables will be send always or only if the button has been clicked, so you run into problems when a user uses [ENTER] to submit the form in some browsers.

Check another variable, e.g. `$_POST['contactemail']` , instead.

Comment: Thanks. I changed it to `if(isset($_POST['contactemail']))` instead. Is is good practice to check for an element rather than the submit/image button? i.e. what if the email field happens to be the field that the user has left omitted. Is there a way to force the contactsubmit_x or contactsubmit_y values?

Comment: It doesn't matter if the field has been ommitted, it will also get submitted if it is empty.

Comment: Not to mention that the HTML5 spec says to only send the `_x` and `_y` bits, so once WebKit is updated to follow the spec it'll stop sending them too.

Answer (score 0):

I have just looked at your form and it seems to be working ok here using FF 3.6.10.
I think this is a caching issue, clear your browsers cache and try again.

Also you may want to look at the Web Devoloper plugin for FF as it offers an easy way to disable/enable your cache. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/

As php is server side it will not be affected by different browsers.

Kind regards
Garry

Comment: Thanks for information but Dr.Molle's suggestion regarding the use of an image as a submit button is the root of the issue.